# How to close the navigation drawer after clicking on item in RecyclerView that is in the nav drawer

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer that has a RecyclerView inside of it. When clicking on an item in the RecyclerView I successfully can navigate to my desired activity using this RecyclerAdapter:

```
public class AdapterNavigation extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNavigation.Holder> {

    private List<NavigationItem> mItemList;
    private Context mContext;


    //this class takes a context and a list of the items you want to populate into the recycler view
    public AdapterNavigation(Context context, List<NavigationItem> itemList) {
        mItemList = itemList;
        mContext = context;


    }
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        //our xml showing how one row looks
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_navigation, viewGroup, false);


        Holder holder = new Holder(row);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, final int position) {
        holder.recyclerNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Intent intent;
                switch (position){
                    //specify what activity will launch on click
                    case 0:
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, Maintenance.class);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, Contact.class);
                        break;
                    default:
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                        break;
                }

                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        NavigationItem item = mItemList.get(position);

        holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(item.getIcon());
        holder.titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.countTextView.setText(Integer.toString(item.getCount()));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemList.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView iconImageView;
        protected TextView titleTextView;
        protected TextView countTextView;
        protected RelativeLayout recyclerNavigation;

        public Holder(View view) {
            super(view);
            iconImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
            titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            countTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countTextView);
            //the whole view
            recyclerNavigation = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerNavigation);
        }

    }



}
```

Now what I want to do is to have the navigation drawer close right before an item is clicked. The way it looks when you click an item in the navigation menu in the android Gmail app.

So right before:

```
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

I would close the navigation drawer.

The issue is getting a reference to that navigation drawer. I was considering getting the view from the context I have because that is all I have.

Is there a way to do this or would I have to change some of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are creating a clicklistener every time a viewholder is bound. Consider setting a clicklistener to `this` in the constructor of the viewholder. You can use `ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` in the listener.

To answer the question, you already pass a `Context` to the adapter, why not also pass it (and the viewholder) the navigation drawer?

Comment: this is why i created it the way i did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/4990823

Answer (score 1):

get reference of your drawer layout and add the below line before mContext.startActivity(intent);
drawerLayout.closeDrawers();